# PHP Array Count - IF/Elseif

Tags: php, html, wordpress, if-statement

Trying to write a simple PHP function which takes an array, then spits out certain code depending on the count of the array. On my test case, of two users, the first `if` took place, when the second one should have.

Below is the code:

I think the problem lies in these:

`if (count($users) == '1' || '3') {`

`if (count($users) == '2' || '4') {`

But I'm not sure!

```
  <?php
    $template_directory = get_template_directory_uri();
    $users = get_users();
    if (count($users) == '1' || '3') {
      foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user->displayname != '') {
          echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">';
            echo '<div class="selection-member">';
              echo '<div class="individual-pic">'.get_avatar($user).'</div>';
              echo '<h4 class="selection-name">' .$user->displayname. '</h5>';
              echo '<h5 class="grey-tagline">'.$user->jobtitle.'</h5>';
              echo '<div class="selection-text quick-center">';
                echo '<p>' . $user->desc . '</p>';
              echo '</div> <!-- end selection-text -->';
              echo '<div class="team-twitter">';
                echo '<a href="http://twitter.com/'.$user->twitter.'"><svg width="36" height="36">';
                  echo '<image xlink:href="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/team-twitter.svg" src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/team-twitter.png" width="36" height="36"/>';
                echo '</svg></a>';
              echo '</div> <!-- end team-twitter -->';
            echo '</div> <!-- end selection-member -->';
          echo '</div> <!-- end col-lg-4 -->';
        }
      }
    }

    elseif (count($users) == '2' || '4') {
      foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user->displayname != '') {
          echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-6 col-sm-6">';
            echo '<div class="selection-member">';
              echo '<div class="individual-pic">'.get_avatar($user).'</div>';
              echo '<h4 class="selection-name">' .$user->displayname. '</h5>';
              echo '<h5 class="grey-tagline">'.$user->jobtitle.'</h5>';
              echo '<div class="selection-text quick-center">';
                echo '<p>' . $user->desc . '</p>';
              echo '</div> <!-- end selection-text -->';
              echo '<div class="team-twitter">';
                echo '<a href="http://twitter.com/'.$user->twitter.'"><svg width="36" height="36">';
                  echo '<image xlink:href="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/team-twitter.svg" src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/team-twitter.png" width="36" height="36"/>';
                echo '</svg></a>';
              echo '</div> <!-- end team-twitter -->';
            echo '</div> <!-- end selection-member -->';
          echo '</div> <!-- end col-lg-4 -->';
          echo '<div class="col-lg-1"></div>';
        }
      }
    } 
  ?>
```

Thanks!

Edit: Thanks so much guys. I'm new to PHP. Thank you!

Comment: any reason you're using triple equals? ===. double would suffice, no?

Comment: Right. Replace `count($users) === '2' || '4'` with `count($users) == '2' || count($users) == '4'`.

Comment: @JPLew totally. But neither work.

Comment: @tmh didn't work either.

Comment: `count($users) === '1' || '3'` is always true! please consider 'tmh' comment

Comment: @tmh is correct. combine that with the double equals and you should be set. Also you don't need to wrap your integers with quotation marks.

Answer (score 3):

The `count()` of an array is always an integer.

But you compared it with a string. And you did so with the strict comparison `===`. This simply will not work.

`if (count($array) == 2)` really is enough to act when the count is two.

The second problem: If you want to compare the count with two values, you'd either have to write TWO comparisons, or use a different construct.

`if (count($array) == 2 || count($array) == 4)` if something should happen on two or four.

`if (in_array(count($array), array(2, 4)))` is the more complex version, which can be extended to as many values you want.

Alternatively, you can use `switch`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: or `if(count($users) % 2 === 0)...`

Comment: If there can be more than 4 values, the modulo solution is definitely more elegant. With only 4 values, it's probably more readable to put them in the code literally.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things wrong with this:

```
if (count($users) === '1' || '3') {
```

Firstly, you're comparing `$users` with a string containing `1` - that's what the single quotes mean. Because you're using `===`, it's also comparing the types, which means that you're not going to get a match.

Secondly, the second part of the `if` statement will always resolve to true. It's effectively:

```
if ('3') {
```

You're checking to see if the string literal '3' is true; the [documentation for type casting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) shows what PHP will cast to 'false', and a string with any value other than 0 will be true.

You need to write your if statement as:

```
if (count($users) == 1 || count($users) == 3) {
```

Comment: the `OR` condition is effectively `if ('3') {`

Comment: @crush - I can see exactly what you're saying, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to put it into English. :D

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your if statements:

1. You use the `===` operator, which does strict type checking. `'2'` in quotes is a string, which simply isn't an integer, so you can't compare it to the result of `count`, which is an integer, at least not when expecting useful results. A string never strictly equals an integer. This will always evaulate to `false`, so either remove the quotes, or use the `==` operator.
2. You write `count... == '2' || '4'` where the correct syntax is `count... == '2' || count... == '4'`. In the first case, you basically say "either `count == '2'` or `'4'` (or both) must be `true`". The statement `'4'` always evaluates to `true`. So you have `something || true`, which also always evaluates to `true`.